# Applying a function to each object in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[ {name:'hi',data:'1,2,3,4,5'} , {name:'hello',data:'5,4,3,2,1'} ]
```

What I need is to apply a split on `data` of each object in array so that the result would be:

```
[ {name:'hi',data:[1,2,3,4,5]} , {name:'hello',data:[5,4,3,2,1]} ]
```

I know I can loop through the array using `for each` and produce a new array, but is there a better, faster method?

```
var arr = [{
    name: 'hi',
    data: '1,2,3,4,5'
}, {
    name: 'hello',
    data: '5,4,3,2,1'
}];

var new_arr = [];
for (i in arr) {
    var temp = {};
    temp.name = arr[i].name;
    temp.data = arr[i].data.split(',');
    new_arr.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to make a new array? Can you just adjust the original?

Comment: [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Don't use `for...in` loops to iterate arrays!

Comment: @epascarello no i dont need new array all what i need is to adjust original

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
var data = [{
    name: 'hi',
    data: '1,2,3,4,5'
}, {
    name: 'hello',
    data: '5,4,3,2,1'
}];
```

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `data` to construct a new Array, like this

```
var result = data.map(function (currentObject) {
    return {
        name: currentObject.name,
        data: currentObject.data.split(",").map(Number)
    };
});
```

Here, we `split` the `currentObject.data` based on `,` and then we call `Number` function on all the split strings, so that you will get the result object's `data` as numbers, as you wanted in the question.

**Output**

```
[{
    name: 'hi',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}, {
    name: 'hello',
    data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
}]
```

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'hi',
    data: '1,2,3,4,5'
  }, {
    name: 'hello',
    data: '5,4,3,2,1'
  }],
  result = data.map(function(currentObject) {
    return {
      name: currentObject.name,
      data: currentObject.data.split(",").map(Number)
    };
  });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 91):

You could use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var new_array = old_array.map(function(e) { 
  e.data = e.data.split(','); 
  return e;
});
```

*As the comment said, this way changes the `old_array`.  You could also return a new object in the [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) function without changing the original array.*

Comment: Note this modifies the objects in `old_array`.

Comment: @xdazz is right you can see for yourself [here](http://jsbin.com/dorogobose/2/edit)

Comment: Apparently excluding the `return e;` still gives the same result. Also, if you're intentionally changing the `old_array`, then `var new array =` is also unneeded. Therefore, a shorter version is: `old_array.map(function(e){ e.data = e.data.split(',') });`