# Using The .replaceAll() on a string literal array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, replaceall

**Goal:** Use an array method to remove the strings `get`, `right`, `the`, `first`, `time` and replace them with the single string know in secretMessage array.

**Plan** Define a function to text in the rain, the old string, and the new string and use to `.replaceall()` methods and pass each one of the different arguments through one at a time, reassigning the array each call.

**Code Thus Far**

```js
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];
    

function replaceWords(orginalArray,oldString,updatedString){=
  let updatedArray= orginalArray.replaceAll(oldString,updatedString);//Not Sure If I need to wrap this in []
  return updatedArray;
}
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'get','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'right','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'the','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'first','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'time','know');

console.log(secretMessage);
```

**Current Results**

```
let updatedArray= orginalArray.replaceAll(oldString,updatedString);
                               ^
```

**TypeError**:

> orginalArray.replaceAll is not a function at replaceWords

Comment: I generally would just loop through the main array containing safe-words. Then check if the other array includes the selected safe-word (as it's looping). Then I would splice(index,1) and go from there. Reason for backwards is to not mess up index when we break it down on removals.

Comment: `.replaceAll()` is a **string** method, not an array method.

Comment: "*Define a function to text in the rain...*" - what?

Comment: Apart from what @Pointy already mentioned, please also pay attention to the difference between the strings `'time,'` and `'time'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for "fun", a solution using both an array method (`Array.prototype.join()`) *and* `replaceAll()` (`String.prototype.replaceAll()`) and close to your original idea, could be:

```js
function replaceWords(arr, oldStr, newStr) {
  return arr.join(' ')          // join all the array items into a single space-separated string
    .replaceAll(oldStr, newStr) // call `replaceAll()` on the newly created string
    .split(' ');                // split the string back into an array
}

let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];

secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage, 'get', 'know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage, 'right', 'know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage, 'the', 'know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage, 'first', 'know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage, 'time', 'know');

console.log(secretMessage);
```

Having said that, I think nobody would do it in that way in real life ;)

Comment: Thanks! Opens my Mind up -if the map method didn't exist I def would have been asking how to go this route

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [@Pointy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70542806/using-the-replaceall-on-a-string-literal-array-in-javascript#comment124698703_70542806), [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) is a string method, it's not available on an array.

---

So we'll need a way [to apply *something* on each array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776996/applying-a-function-to-each-object-in-a-javascript-array).

---

Luckily [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does exactly that:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function **on every element in the calling array**.

```js
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];
    

function replaceWords(orginalArray,oldString,updatedString){
  return orginalArray.map(item => {
    return item.replaceAll(oldString, updatedString)
  });
}
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'get','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'right','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'the','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'first','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'time','know');

console.log(secretMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` is **String** function, not an **Array** function. If you want to replace a word that maybe exists as value in an array, you have to walk through that array. Your code would look like this:

```js
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];
    

function replaceWords(orginalArray,oldString,updatedString){
  /* because your array values are just single words 
  and you want to replace the whole word with another whole word, 
  you can use string comparison instead of replaceAll() */
  
  let updatedArray= orginalArray.map(string => (string == oldString ? updatedString : string));
  return updatedArray;
}
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'get','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'right','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'the','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'first','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'time','know');

console.log(secretMessage);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the array functionality to match your requirement. But not recommended.

Just add below code before your array declaration and your code should work.

```
Array.prototype.replaceAll = function(oldString, updatedString){
    return this.slice().map((str)=>((str === oldString)?updatedString:str));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`replaceAll()` works for strings not arrays. Try the example below.

```
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];
    

function replaceWords(orginalArray,oldString,updatedString){=
  let updatedArray= orginalArray.join().replaceAll(oldString,updatedString).split();
  return updatedArray;
}
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'get','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'right','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'the','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'first','know');
secretMessage = replaceWords(secretMessage,'time','know');

console.log(secretMessage);
```

Comment: `.split()` is also a string method, not an array method.

Comment: Whoops, fixed, thanks